# Overriding server connector config with env variables with dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have posted this question on dw mailing list but didnt get an answer.

Can I assume the YML format below doesnt work for DW 0.7.0 anymore? (The use of @ char to insert env var)

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      bindHost: @OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP@
      port: @OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT@
```

Error:

> Malformed YAML at line: 28, column: 17; while scanning for the next token; found character @ '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation);  in 'reader', line 28, column 17:
>             bindHost: @OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP@

So I decided to use this format:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
      type: http
      bindHost: localhost
      port: 8080
```

And tried to override it via jvm options:

```
java -Ddw.server.connector.bindHost=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP -Ddw.server.connector.port=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT -jar target/myapp.jar server myapp.yml
```

My local env variables:

```
OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP=localhost
OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT=8080
```

The error I got from this setup:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener.lifeCycleStarting(SetUIDListener.java:213)
>       ...
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:157)
>       ...
>   WARN  [2014-05-03 20:11:19,412] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@91b85: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Starting from Dropwizard version **0.8.0**, you can access environment variables from the configuration yml file. It also supports setting a default value in case the environment variable is not available.
[See the docs here.](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.3/docs/manual/core.html#environment-variables)

**Example**

```
// put environment variable inside ${}
// use :- operator to provide default value

dbHost: ${DB_HOST}
dbPort: ${DB_PORT:-1234}
// dbPort = 1234, if DB_PORT environment variable has no value
```

**Important Note**: For this to work you need to set up a `SubstitutingSourceProvider` with an `EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor`.

```
// Enable variable substitution with environment variables
bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
    new SubstitutingSourceProvider(
        bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
        new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor())
);
```

**Update**: 15/Nov/2017
As mentioned by @EFreak in the comments section, `new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor()` will throw `UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException` if the environment variable is not defined, unless you set `strict` mode to `false` by using `new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)`
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.java

Comment: @StephenNYC this should be the accepted answer now, as it's built into dropwizard

Comment: @Warfox, as of dropwizard `1.1.4`, in order to get default values to work, you need to disable strict mode using `new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)`. Else it will throw `UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException` src: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.java

Answer (score 6):

someone created a [bundle](https://github.com/minisu/Dropwizard-EnvVar-Interpolation) for DW to be able to embed env vars