# Dropwizard Enviornment Variable Substitution Type Check Error

Tags: java, environment-variables, config, dropwizard

I'm a Dropwizard newbie and am using an existing Dropwizard service, where I am attempting to create YML values that are overridable depending on the environment that my service is deployed to (i.e. Dev, QA, Prod). I tried Googling my error message, but really didn't find a whole lot for this specific error, so I thought that I would post a new question for this.

When I run my script that starts the service, I get the following error:

```
my-host:my-service jthoms$ ./start.sh 3.0.0
Starting my-service...
src/main/resources/configuration.yml has an error:
  * Incorrect type of value at: downstream_service.loggingEnabled; is of type: String, expected: boolean
```

Note that I have already created a `MyServiceConfiguration` class which extends Dropwizard's main `Configuration` class and delegates to a `DownstreamServiceConfiguration` class that has a boolean field for the `loggingEnabled` property. I did this in accordance with the [Dropwizard Core doc](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.6.2/manual/core.html).

My `start.sh` script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Please pass jar version! Usage: ./start.sh <jar_version>"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Starting my-service with version '$1'"

java $DEBUG_ARGS -Xmx128m -jar target/my-service-$1.jar server src/main/resources/configuration.yml
```

My `configuration.yml` is as follows:

```
server:
  ...
downstream_service:
  loggingEnabled: ${DW_DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_LOGGING_ENABLED}
  ...
logging:
  ...
```

I don't understand what's causing this type safety error. How can I import my environment variables to Dropwizard as a non-string type?

Comment: Yes. If it wasn’t solved at the time, I wouldn’t have added the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling around, I found the solution(s) to my issue, and thought that I would share my answer here for others with the same error message I was getting.

The problem wasn't that my boolean `DW_DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_LOGGING_ENABLED` environment was being treated as a string, the problem was the boolean YML property just wasn't being wired up correctly, so the string value it was finding wasn't the string literal, `true`. Rather, it was the string literal `${DW_DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_LOGGING_ENABLED}`. Basically, Dropwizard just wasn't substituting `${DW_DOWNSTREAM_SERVICE_LOGGING_ENABLED}` for `true` in the first place.

The solution involved two things:

1. Call the script that actually creates the environment variables from my `start.sh` script. I had actually forgotten to do this. Doh!
2. Configure the application's bootstrap to use an `EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231630/4851565). Note that you don't need to set the `EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor` to use [non-strict checking](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.8.0-rc5/dropwizard-configuration/apidocs/io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.html#EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(boolean,%20boolean)), the shell variables aren't being unconditionally interpreted as strings by Dropwizard. The following code needs to be added to your main Application class.

   ```
   @Override
   public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
       bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
               new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
                       new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor()));
   }
   ```

Those two things combined solved the problem.