# Dropwizard and Hashicorp Vault

Tags: dropwizard, hashicorp-vault

I'm wondering if anyone has experience using Dropwizard and Vault together? I'm looking for a solution where I can keep my DB and other passwords in Vault instead of the dropwizard .yaml configuration. I'd also like to be able to start my service up and be prompted for the Vault key and not place any secrets in any config files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553673/dropwizard-configuration-file-security) and my comments there. They are not directly connected to your question but maybe will help you.

Comment: Why not use an environment variable to save the vault key? Prompting the user at startup means that your service can't auto-restart.